# \thispagestyle{plain} does not work for the 3rd page from list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, fancyhdr, pagestyle

I'm trying to create a plain page style for list of figures using the `\thispagestyle{plain}` command but it only works for the first 2 pages. On the third page, it uses the `\pagestyle{fancy}`, with header and footer. I also tried the `\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{plain}}` command but it didn't work either. How do I create a plain page style for the 3rd page as well?

Comment: `\thispagestyle` is for one page. You need `\pagestyle{plain}` if you want to affect more than one.